# Get and Insert MongoDB auto generated UUID into current record

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I have need to insert a MongoDB auto generated UUID into my another column like below code,

```
try:
    conn = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    print("Connected successfully!!!")
except:
    print("Could not connect to MongoDB")

# database
db = conn.hash
# Created or Switched to collection names: my_gfg_collection
collection = db.ib
unix = datetime.utcnow()
unixtime = calendar.timegm(unix.utctimetuple())

emp_rec1 = {
    "tib" : "8f7074d8-a520-4f7d-b2d3-09dc36acb5fd",
    "tib_name" : "TPEMAIL",
    "mail_box_name" : "Test Gmail",
    "id_mail_box" : "use here when generate to UUID v4 - MONGO",          
}
# Insert Data
    rec_id1 = collection.insert_one(emp_rec1)
```

As show in above code I will need to insert auto generated UUID (_id:5b5a36d40abd950a88003fc3) into my `id_mail_box` column.

Comment: what does it mean "I will need to add auto generated UUID insert record time into my `id_mail_box` column"? auto-generated by who?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov sir, When I have insert one record in mongoDB that time mongo create one UUID like '_id: ObjectId (5b5a36d40abd950a88003fc3)'.So, I need to insert same UUID in id_mail_box column

Comment: and you want to get this id back?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov , yes and need to update or insert in current record column

Comment: why do you need that? `_id` is a **MongoDB** implementation detail, why not just generate your own UUID?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov , ok sir. I think it will use in future for reference key.But, now I will use create own uuid.Thanks